# how to add parameters in report viewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, header, reportviewer

HY! I have a form application in visual studio 2010 and I want to create a report with report viewer and to add some parameters. I tried to add parameters from code but it didn`t work. I have this error:

FilterExpression expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ refers to the field ‘datastart’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.
Report2.rdlc : error rsParameterReference: The FilterValue expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ refers to a non-existing report parameter ‘datastart’.

In my code a do this:

```
 private void SetReportParameters()
    {
        ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
        parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("datastart", dateTimePickerStartRaport.Text);
        parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("dataStop", dateTimePickerStopRaport.Text);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
    }
```

and after calling this method a make a refresh on the report viewer

```
 reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I also look at other forums and I saw that I have to add the parameters to the report, but  I didn`t manage out how must I do this. I also tried to add, in the properties windows of the report, some filters with value

```
  =Parameters!datastart.Value
```

but this also didn`t work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error you get is because you try to specify your parameter like a field. In the expression-designer you have a special category called "Parameters". From there you can access your parameters.
The syntax is `=Parameters![FieldName].Value`. In your case for example `=Parameters!datastart.Value`.

Additionaly, note that the parameters must be declared in the "Report Data"-window under "Parameters". Its the same window as you use to declare your recordsets, however there is also a special category for parameters. There are also some options for the datatype and if specification of the parameter is mandatory.

Comment: And where it is the Report Data window?

Comment: In ViewMenu of visual studio, the last menu item: "Report Data"

Comment: *Report Data* window is available also by **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **D** shortcut. It should help if you can't find it in menu.

Answer (score 2):

So when you create report definition (rdl or rdlc file) you have to add parameters with exactly the same names. So for your case you have to add `datastart` and `dataStop` parameters. To do it just click Parameters in Report Data Window and click add new.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ReportParameter PrmInvoiceNo = new ReportParameter("PrmInvoiceNo");
PrmInvoiceNo.Values.Add(this.InvNo.ToString());
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(PrmInvoiceNo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Developer: Bilal Ahmad from Wide Vision Kashmir
Solved:
**=FormatNumber(CDec((Parameters!prmInstallment1.Value))+ CDec((Parameters!Installment2.Value)))**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).