# VB.NET Filling multiple datatables in same dataset, NO SQL - Error

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

Recently I've been trying to mess around with datasets and datatables and I've cam by an issue that I have been trying to figure out for about 2 hours and I've also shredded the Google search button.

```
    Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").NewRow()

    newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = "ALFKI"
    newCustomersRow("CompanyName") = "Alfreds Futterkiste"

    DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
```

Well the issue is not the tables itself since its an untyped dataset with the required tables but I've been getting an error near `DataSet1.Tables`.

> Error: Error  4   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object
>   reference.

Comment: Hows was DataSet1 instantiated?  A server-side query that returns more than one set of records (select * from foo; select * from bar) will yield a DataSet client side when using the DataAdapter.

Comment: Your DataSet1 is designed using Visual Studio or have you built it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an instance of your `DataSet1`.

For example:

```
Dim ds1 As New DataSet1
Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = ds1.Tables("Customers").NewRow()

newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = "ALFKI"
newCustomersRow("CompanyName") = "Alfreds Futterkiste"

ds1.Tables("Customers").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
```

This will create your `DataSet1` object reference

Comment: Your code gives me the error below while debugging: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  And it also gives me a warring Warning 1 Variable 'ds1' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: @user2551193 Oh, sorry I forgot the keyword `New` when declaring the dataset.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112467995/CrystalReportTest01.zip As you see in my project the second datatable will not be shown on my Crystal Report, anyone? That's all I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2551193 Unfortunately I do not have CrystalReports installed anymore (causing many errors). Ever since I had a new computer at work, I use Microsoft's ReportViewer (VS Professional). It's free and basically the same thing.

Comment: For more information on ReportViewer, I have made multiple questions / answers. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940074/reportviewer-programmatically-generate-report