# Custom export reportviewer to excel file

Tags: c#, sql, reportviewer

I want to export the report viewer to excel file after clicking a button and hide the existing export toolstrip button that available for report viewer.

Below is my code for ExportFile function:

```
 private void ExportFile()
    {
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "*PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Doc files      (*.doc)|*.doc";
        // Variables
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        string path = " ";
        DialogResult dr = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

        byte[] bytes = reportViewerForm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out   mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + ".xls", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();}
```

Code for button_click event:

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetData();
        this.ExportFile();
    }
```

However, I get a exception error when trying to export it. 
Here is my inner exception:

```
 InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException
   Message=One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified.
   Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
   ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsParametersNotSpecified&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=1.0
   SkipTopLevelMessage=false
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition, Boolean& dataCached)
        at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CreateSnapshotAndRender(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, ReportProcessing repProc, IRenderingExtension renderer, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, SubreportCallbackHandler subreportHandler, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials)
        at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, ParameterInfoCollection reportParameters, IEnumerable dataSources, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
        at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
   InnerException:
```

What parameter did I missing? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the report you are trying to export require Report Parameters?
(Quick Info on Parameters: [how to add parameters in report viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103784/how-to-add-parameters-in-report-viewer))

I ask because that's usually the Exception I get when I forget to pass my report Parameters.

Comment: Yes, I have some parameters on header. How can I pass the report parameters.