# how to refresh data in reportviewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a reportviewer in a webform named `WebForm1` using 2 parameters named `fromDate` and `toDate` to filter data.  The webform shows data when it loads. Problem is that when I change the `fromDate`, `toDate` field and click button1 to submit, **it goes back to default date** and reload with the same data.  How do I refresh the reportviewer data with the new input date?  How do I use reportviewer in a webform (not winform) with parameters?  Thanks for any help.

Here is my **WebForm1.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

    { 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.fromDate.Text = "8/6/2015";
            this.toDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to study about how to pass Parameter and refresh reportviewer. Look for how to pass parameter to report viewer in google and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103784/how-to-add-parameters-in-report-viewer also help you.

Comment: @user1698255, when u click on button the page gets loaded and fromdate and todate fields are filled with the values you are assigning in page_load method so it is happening like that, just place the two lines of assignment in !IsPostBack then it will be fine,

Answer (score 2):

In the above scenario you are manualy assign fromDate  and toDate values and reload it. No need to assign like that. You can get values from client side text box by using "fromDate.Text". Then pass those values into your method and return correct data to page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set SSRS report parameter from web page as below

```
 string reportPath ="Report relative path"
                // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
                ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;

                string reportserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
                string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];

                // Set the report server URL and report path
                serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportserver);
                serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials(username, password, domain);
                serverReport.ReportPath = reportPath;


ReportParameter[] parameters;
                    parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
                    parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("fromDate", "8/6/2015");
                    parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("toDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```